# Where to find gene manipulation video (or photos)

Tags: genetics, dna, microscopy, gene

I hope Im not asking a dumb question!

Where can i find video of gene manipulation in action under microscope?
Like extracting a gene from a cell, fixing gene mutations, putting the gene in a vector, that kinda stuff. Is this too small to show in video or photos?

If i look up youtube all I find is scientists using lab machines and equipments except for under miscroscope!!!

Comment: There are no videos of that, since you cannot see the DNA you are working with unless you precipitate it in large amounts.

Comment: You can find videos of microinjections, but you're not actually going to see DNA.

Comment: Like this video http://www.dnatube.com/video/5561/What-is-Blastocyst-Microinjection

Comment: Ok now I understand thanks! So how do scientists manipulate genes if they can't see what they are doing!??

Comment: The comments effectively answer the question. There is no need to close it as broad. The main question here is "*Is this too small to show in video or photos?*" which can be answered. I am voting to leave this open.

Answer (score 3):

From the comment section:

We don't have to see the actual changes. It's like chemists who will mix compounds together and obtain a new molecule. They dont see the chemical reaction per se but can test the new molecule to make sure what they predicted would happen had happened. Finally we often use fluorescent proteins to track some of the modification performed (which could involve a microscope). For the how, well that's a bit broad and involves too many notions to make a summary here.